# Gradle mongo dependency

Tags: mongodb, gradle

I am using mongo dependency using gradle

But getting exception:

```
Could not resolve: org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.6.3
Could not resolve: org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:2.0.6.RELEASE
Could not resolve: org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.6.3
```

My Gradle file look like below :

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations.all {
   exclude group: "commons-logging", module: "commons-logging"
}

dependencies {

    compile 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.6.3'
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:2.0.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver', version: '3.6.3'

    testCompile("org.testng:testng:${testNGVersion}")
    testCompile("junit:junit:${jUnitVersion}")
    testCompile("org.mockito:mockito-core:${mockitoVersion}")
}
```

Can someone please help me why I am getting above exception.

Comment: Looks like it should work https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.6.3

Comment: @cricket_007 have also tried with that compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver', version: '3.6.3' but still getting the same issue

Comment: Are you blocked from accessing Maven Central? Do you need a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to https://start.spring.io/, choose Generate a 'Gradle Project' with 'Java' and whatever Boot version you want, type `mongo` in the "Search for dependencies" and download the project.

Comment: Its generated dependency for spring Boot but I want for spring MVC

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty perhaps you don’t know much about the spring ecosystem because spring data mongo assumes spring boot. Not to mention that you didn’t say clearly in your question that you didn’t want boot

Comment: Regardless of needing it, that doesn't cause a "cannot resolve" error

Comment: @cricket_007 it shouldn’t. There are 2 ways to solve a problem: 1. Find what’s causing it 2. Try something else. Since OP didn’t post his complete build file, instead of shooting in the dark, I chose approach #2

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar absolutely untrue that spring data mongodb assumes spring boot. Might wanna reconsider insulting others based on your incorrect understanding.

Comment: @Madbreaks I don't see any insulting comment here, other than yours. Besides, who hired you as a spokesperson? I'm sure the person I'm talking to can speak for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependency code in `build.gradle` file and re-build project.

```
   dependencies {
          implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    }
```